# How to generate UUID/GUID in Python 2.4 as UUID module is missing

Tags: python, uuid, python-2.4

Not able to find a way to generate UUID in Python 2.4 as the module was made available in Python 2.5 and is stable in 2.7. My machine is centos5 & due to other dependency cant really use or upgrade to Python 2.7

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to backport it (which doesn't sound too hard).

Answer (score 3):

I did it with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import commands

def uuid():
        return commands.getstatusoutput('uuidgen')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        print uuid()[1]
```

It gives nice expected answer e79a890c-5e3a-4c3a-bfdb-5377389b69ac

Comment: Is this RFC 4122 compliant?

Answer (score 2):

The Linux Kernel has support to generate UUID. On my Debian system this functionality is accessible from the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem at `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`:

```
>>> with open('/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid') as f:
...     print(f.read())
... 
1e21ee4f-953e-4179-9bea-ac9a0b9189e7
```

---

If you are able to install `libuuid` you will have access to the `uuidgen` command line tool:

> <sup>From `man uuidgen`</sup>
>
> The  uuidgen program creates (and
>   prints) a new universally unique identifier (UUID) using the libuuid(3) library.  The new UUID can reasonably
>   be  considered  unique  among all UUIDs created on the local system, and
>          among UUIDs created on other systems in the past and in the future.

```
sh$ uuidgen 
c5f243c6-eb85-4eb9-a20e-97684d4baa1c
```

Comment: I'm using CentOS5 and it seem not to have '/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid'

Comment: Try `find /proc -name uuid` -- just in case... Probably your kernel was compiled without support for that feature ? Or just too old ? No hope to install libuuid neither ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this: https://gist.github.com/mahmoudimus/56bcec09b69a2b5165aa

It's a python 2.3+ compatible version of the uuid module.

Example:

```
curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mahmoudimus/56bcec09b69a2b5165aa/raw/b1dd7633fff6ca0cc84a3b1fe435db7c65180dac/uuid.py
```

Use:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.__file__
'uuid.py'
>>> uuid.uuid1()
UUID('520a35d2-308f-11e4-b49f-600308a2f4f0')
>>> uuid.uuid1().hex
'53bcd6be308f11e4b49f600308a2f4f0'
```

You can also just use: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyuuid/0.0.1

```
pip install pyuuid
```

Answer (score 0):

After bit of research, I found out that the best way to have UUID available in python 2.4 as the exact same as python 2.5+ is to download the UUID module from python source, as it's pure python code, so you can just include it under your project, for example:

```
wget http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/uuid.py


Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:47:03) 
>>> import uuid
>>> print uuid.uuid1
<function uuid1 at 0x2b93db1f7758>
>>> print uuid.uuid1()
e95bdba8-652d-11e6-a87a-005056bf0031
```